# How to show &mdash in my Razor expression

Tags: syntax, razor

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to integrate an emdash into a string in Razor. Here's the idea:

```
@( string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DemandClassCode) ? string.Empty : Model.DemandClassCode &mdash; Model.DemandClassName)
```

I'm getting a ReSharper error message in the editor:

Cannot resolve symbol 'mdash'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor automatically HTML encodes all the output which is not `HtmlString`.

Use `Html.Raw` helper if you don't want encoding:

```
@Html.Raw(isValid ? "" : string.Format("{0} &mdash; {1}", @Model.Var1, @Model.Var2) )
```

Or create the `HtmlString` explicitly:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(isValid ? "" : string.Format("{0} &mdash; {1}", @Model.Var1, @Model.Var2))
```

And with your new sample:

```
@Html.Raw(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DemandClassCode) ? string.Empty : string.Format("{0} &mdash; {1}", Model.DemandClassCode, Model.DemandClassName))
```

Or with using if:

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DemandClassCode))
{
    @string.Empty
}
else
{
    <text>@Model.DemandClassCode &mdash; @Model.DemandClassName</text>
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error message. These don't seem to be working. I tried both of them.

Comment: Have you tried together with the `string.Format`? Because you need to return string that is why resharper complains in your new sample.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! Just didn't have quite the right combination.